# android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Could not allocate CursorWindow due to error -12

Tags: android

Using RoomDB database

Crashlog

````
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/user/0/com.exaplem.myapps/no_backup/test.db' of size 2097152 due to error -12.
t android.database.CursorWindow.nativeCreate (Native Method)
at android.database.CursorWindow.<init> (CursorWindow.java:139)
at android.database.CursorWindow.<init> (CursorWindow.java:120)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow (AbstractWindowedCursor.java:202)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow (SQLiteCursor.java:147)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount (SQLiteCursor.java:140)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition (AbstractCursor.java:232)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext (AbstractCursor.java:281)
at androidx.room.InvalidationTracker$1.checkUpdatedTable (InvalidationTracker.java:464)
at androidx.room.InvalidationTracker$1.run (InvalidationTracker.java:437)
at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run (SerialExecutor.java:91)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)```
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems that several cursors are opening and causing memory leaks.

I'm working on the same problem, but with SQLite, so I'll update when I figure things out.

Tip: Close cursors when you're done using them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).